# Cordova sms plugin capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native, capacitor

I have a problem in my app, I installed npm install cordova-sms-plugin
npm install @ionic-native/sms, and run command npx cap sync but doesn’t work, when update iOS, please your help. look at the image, it stays in that state[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information? What doesn't work?

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering, the problem was the bandwidth of the internet.